# App name already exists in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I wanted to add an app to the App Store, so in order to check the things required to submit an app I filled some of the information and proceeded until the screenshots submission page in iTunes Connect. Then I didn't have the screenshots and app logo, so I saved the information so that I could upload the screenshots and other information later.

Now when I go to iTunes Connect when I search by that name it shows no
records found. And when I try to add a new app and enter the same name
it gives an error app name already taken. Can someone let me know how
to get access to previously saved information or to add a new app with
same app name.

Answer (score 5):

Common problem, someone already created an app with this name but didn't submit it to the AppStore yet.
Still, the name is blocked and cannot be deleted so you will never be able to have it back, except if you directly inform Apple.

Also, if you create an App and then delete it, the name will be blocked forever.
I personally did it and asked directly to Apple to give me back the name and it worked after 2 weeks of negotiation.

Comment: We're facing this issue just now. Would you mind sharing who you contacted at Apple to resolve this?

Comment: I would like to know that as well.

Comment: For future reference this where you submit an app name dispute https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appnamenotices/

Answer (score 1):

The app you created previously should be there in your itunes connect if you have not deleted that app from your itunes Connect.

Once you have taken an app name and if its saved then apple will not allow you to take the same name again.

Also the name you are trying to take but someone else has given that name but not submitted the app, then also you won't be able to take that app name.

You have to take different name of your app.

Comment: I had an app with the name I wanted but I deleted that but now I realize that I want it back. Whom can I speak with at Apple to release that name. Our business is registered under that name so it is very serious. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you created an entry for the first App in iTunesConnect, even if it was never submitted or uploaded, then that name is locked to that iTunesConnect App permanently. That means if another user have choose same name already but still not upload and release app than you will not able to find on itunes store.
See [Apple app store tips](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html)

> The name you select for your app is perhaps one of the most important aspects to marketing your app and can **distinguish** your app on the App Store.
>   *If you submit an app name which is already in use within the same geography in which your app is sold, you will be prompted to enter another name.*

You can find more info in [iTunesconnect Developer's guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

Comment: When you create and app there is no place to mention the "geography" of the app. Is this from the app language we set?

Comment: @Maziyar "geography" mean to say, countries which you have selected for sell the app. It is available in iTunesConnect.